# Как добавить "функцию ходьбы" главному герою игры, используя JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, разработка-игр

Пишу игру на JS. Добавил персонажа в игру. Нужно научить его ходить. Ходить он должен при влево и вправо при нажатии на кнопку на клавиатуре. У меня есть некоторые варианты того, как это можно сделать, но мне кажется, что есть куда более успешные реализации.

Да, кстати, в примере(который будет дальше) главный герой - черный прямоугольник, в реальном проекте я нарисовал главного героя в ФШ и добавил его на холст, используя `drawImage()`.

Код: 
 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id = "main"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
function init () {
 window.onload = function () {
  var canv = document.getElementById("main"),
      ctx  = canv.getContext("2d"),

      h = canv.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      w = canv.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // ground
   ctx.fillStyle = "#8BC34A";

   ctx.fillRect(0, canv.height - 40, canv.width, 40);

   // player
   ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

   ctx.fillRect(canv.width / 2 - 20, canv.height - (40 + 80), 40, 80);

   function update () {
     // code

     requestAnimationFrame(update);
   }

   update();
 }
}

init();
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMMzMQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const canv = document.getElementById("main"),
      ctx  = canv.getContext("2d"),
      h = canv.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      w = canv.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

// ground
ctx.fillStyle = "#8BC34A";
ctx.fillRect(0, canv.height - 40, canv.width, 40);

// player
let playerX = Math.floor(canv.width / 2 - 20);
let playerY = Math.floor(canv.height - (40 + 80));
const playerSpeed = 3;

const renderPlayer = (x, y, w, h) => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

renderPlayer(playerX, playerY, 40, 80);

const go = (evt) => {

  ctx.clearRect(playerX, playerY, 40, 80);
   
  if(evt.keyCode === 39){
    playerX += playerSpeed;
  }else if(evt.keyCode === 37){
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
  }
  
  renderPlayer(playerX, playerY, 40, 80);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(go);
  
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', go);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "main"></canvas>
```